# How to Perform Trigger Operation in parse android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to total the number of employees who are all taking more then 15000 salary.when i add the employee details it will automatically total the employees and give the total number using trigger operation in Parse. how can i do this.

Comment: Do you want to send a push notification to the devices when a new employee is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cloud code, you can add an afterSave trigger:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Employee", function(request) {

    //get the total number of employees that earn more than 15000
    //do push notification or what you want

});
```

When a new "Employee" is inserted, that code will be executed.

Check this link out for more info about triggers:

https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers

Comment: thank you sir.but i am very new for parse and android.i cant able do with this..will you please  briefly tell ..with any one simple example,